# How To Create Invoice/Add Client Remotely WHMCS API?

Tags: php, html, api, curl, whmcs

We have a website which is powered by wordpress. 
We want to include a form in one of our pages which clients can choose products from a checklist html table, Then a pop-up shows and **client enters his name/address/email etc.**
 This info & the chosen products with final price will be used to **create a new client in our WHMCS** & then **creating an invoice** for this client.
I've tried a lot but I don't know where's the problem. 
I've **whitelisted** IP address of remote server in WHMCS security tab.
I've turned on php error display, but nothing shows up.
I've also checked that if remote server is connecting successfully through API. 
All seems going fine. But still no luck.
It just shows :

> An error occured. Please contact support. ()

Here's the code which I'm currently working on:

```
<?php

$whmcsurl = "http://www.yourdomain.com/whmcsfolder/";
$apiusername = "adminuser"; # Admin username goes here
$apipassword = "password"; # Admin password goes here

if ($_POST["action"]=="submit") {

    # Get Values
    $domain = trim(htmlentities($_POST["domain"]));
    $domaintype = trim(htmlentities($_POST["domaintype"]));
    $pid = trim(htmlentities($_POST["pid"]));
    $billingcycle = trim(htmlentities($_POST["billingcycle"]));
    $firstname = trim(htmlentities($_POST["firstname"]));
    $lastname = trim(htmlentities($_POST["lastname"]));
    $companyname = trim(htmlentities($_POST["companyname"]));
    $email = trim(htmlentities($_POST["email"]));
    $address1 = trim(htmlentities($_POST["address1"]));
    $address2 = trim(htmlentities($_POST["address2"]));
    $city = trim(htmlentities($_POST["city"]));
    $state = trim(htmlentities($_POST["state"]));
    $postcode = trim(htmlentities($_POST["postcode"]));
    $country = trim(htmlentities($_POST["country"]));
    $phonenumber = trim(htmlentities($_POST["phonenumber"]));
    $password = trim(htmlentities($_POST["password"]));
    $password2 = trim(htmlentities($_POST["password2"]));
    $paymentmethod = trim(htmlentities($_POST["paymentmethod"]));
    $tosagreement = $_POST["tosagreement"];

    # Error Checking
    if (!$domain) {
        $errors[] = "You did not enter a domain name";
    }
    if (ereg('[^a-z0-9.-]', $domain)) {
        $errors[] = "The domain you entered is not valid";
    }
    if (($billingcycle!="monthly")AND($billingcycle!="annually")) {
        $billingcycle = "monthly";
    }
    if (!$firstname) {
        $errors[] = "You did not enter your first name";
    }
    if (!$lastname) {
        $errors[] = "You did not enter your last name";
    }
    if (!$email) {
        $errors[] = "You did not enter your email address";
    } elseif (!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,6})$", $email)) {
        $errors[] = "The email address you entered is invalid";
    }
    if (!$address1) {
        $errors[] = "You did not enter the first line of your address";
    }
    if (!$city) {
        $errors[] = "You did not enter your city";
    }
    if (!$state) {
        $errors[] = "You did not enter your state";
    }
    if (!$postcode) {
        $errors[] = "You did not enter your postcode";
    }
    if (!$country) {
        $errors[] = "You did not enter your country";
    }
    if (!$phonenumber) {
        $errors[] = "You did not enter your phone number";
    }
    if (!$password) {
        $errors[] = "You must enter a password";
    } elseif ($password!=$password2) {
        $errors[] = "The password you entered did not match";
    }
    if (!$tosagreement) {
        $errors[] = "You must agree to the terms of service";
    }

    if (!$errors) {

        # Submit Order

        $apiurl = $whmcsurl."includes/api.php"; # URL to WHMCS API file

        $postfields = array();
        $postfields["username"] = $apiusername;
        $postfields["password"] = md5($apipassword);
        $postfields["action"] = "addclient";
        $postfields["firstname"] = $firstname;
        $postfields["lastname"] = $lastname;
        $postfields["companyname"] = $companyname;
        $postfields["email"] = $email;
        $postfields["address1"] = $address1;
        $postfields["address2"] = $address2;
        $postfields["city"] = $city;
        $postfields["state"] = $state;
        $postfields["postcode"] = $postcode;
        $postfields["country"] = $country;
        $postfields["phonenumber"] = $phonenumber;
        $postfields["password2"] = $password;

        $query_string = "";
        foreach ($postfields AS $k=>$v) {
            $query_string .= "$k=".urlencode($v)."&";
        }

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiurl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $data = explode(";",$data);
        foreach ($data AS $temp) {
            $temp = explode("=",$temp);
            $results[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
        }

        if ($results["result"]=="success") {
            $clientid = $results["clientid"];
        } else {
            die("An error occured. Please contact support. ({$results['message']})");
        }

        $postfields = array();
        $postfields["username"] = $apiusername;
        $postfields["password"] = md5($apipassword);
        $postfields["action"] = "addorder";
        $postfields["clientid"] = $clientid;
        $postfields["pid"] = $pid;
        $postfields["domain"] = $domain;
        if (($domaintype=="register")OR($domaintype=="transfer")) {
            $postfields["domaintype"] = $domaintype;
            $postfields["regperiod"] = 1;
        }
        $postfields["billingcycle"] = $billingcycle;
        $postfields["paymentmethod"] = $paymentmethod;

        $query_string = "";
        foreach ($postfields AS $k=>$v) {
            $query_string .= "$k=".urlencode($v)."&";
        }

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiurl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $data = explode(";",$data);
        foreach ($data AS $temp) {
            $temp = explode("=",$temp);
            $results[$temp[0]] = $temp[1];
        }

        if ($results["result"]=="success") {
            $invoiceid = $results["invoiceid"];
            header("Location: ".$whmcsurl."dologin.php?username=$email&password=$password&goto=viewinvoice&id=$invoiceid");
            exit;
        } else {
            die("An error occured. Please contact support. ({$results['message']})");
        }

    }

}

?><html>
<head>
<title>Order Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Order Form</h1>

<?php
if ($errors) {
    echo "<p>The following errors occured.</p><ul>";
    foreach ($errors AS $error) {
        echo "<li>$error</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit" />

<table>
<tr><td width="150"><b>Domain Details</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>Domain Name</td><td>www. <input type="text" name="domain" size="40" value="<?php echo $domain ?>" /> (eg. mydomain.com)</td></tr>
<tr><td>Domain Type</td><td>
<input type="radio" name="domaintype" value="register"<?php if (($domaintype=="register")OR(!$domaintype)) { echo " checked"; } ?> /> I want to register this as a new domain<br />
<input type="radio" name="domaintype" value="transfer"<?php if ($domaintype=="transfer") { echo " checked"; } ?> /> I already own this domain and want to transfer it to you<br />
<input type="radio" name="domaintype" value="owndomain"<?php if ($domaintype=="owndomain") { echo " checked"; } ?> /> I own this domain and will change the nameservers at my existing registrar</td></tr>
<tr><td><br /></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Hosting Details</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>Hosting Package</td><td>
<input type="radio" name="pid" value="1"<?php if (($pid=="1")OR(!$pid)) { echo " checked"; } ?> /> Starter Package
<input type="radio" name="pid" value="2"<?php if ($pid=="2") { echo " checked"; } ?> /> Standard Package
<input type="radio" name="pid" value="3"<?php if ($pid=="3") { echo " checked"; } ?> /> Advanced Package
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Billing Cycle</td><td><select name="billingcycle"><option value="monthly"<?php if ($billingcycle=="monthly") { echo " selected"; } ?>>Monthly</option><option value="annually"<?php if ($billingcycle=="annually") { echo " selected"; } ?>>Annually</option></select></td></tr>
<tr><td><br /></td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Your Details</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>First Name</td><td><input type="text" name="firstname" size="30" value="<?php echo $firstname ?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name</td><td><input type="text" name="lastname" size="30" value="<?php echo $lastname ?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Company Name</td><td><input type="text" name="companyname" value="<?php echo $companyname ?>" size="30" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email Address</td><td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" size="30" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address 1</td><td><input type="text" name="address1" value="<?php echo $address1 ?>" size="30" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address 2</td><td><input type="text" name="address2" value="<?php echo $address2 ?>" size="30" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>City</td><td><input type="text" name="city" size="30" value="<?php echo $city ?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>State</td><td><input type="text" name="state" size="30" value="<?php echo $state ?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Postcode</td><td><input type="text" name="postcode" size="30" value="<?php echo $postcode ?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Country</td><td><input type="text" name="country" size="30" value="<?php echo $country ?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Phone Number</td><td><input type="text" name="phonenumber" size="30" value="<?php echo $phonenumber ?>" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Payment Method</td><td>
<input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" value="paypal"<?php if (($paymentmethod=="paypal")OR(!$paymentmethod)) { echo " checked"; } ?> /> PayPal
<input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" value="authorize"<?php if ($paymentmethod=="authorize") { echo " checked"; } ?> /> Credit Card
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="password" size="30" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Confirm Password</td><td><input type="password" name="password2" size="30" /></td></tr>
</table>

<p align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="tosagreement" /> I have read and agree to the <a href="http://www.yourdomain.com/terms.html" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a></p>

<p align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit Order" /></p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```